# jquery namespace for dynamic page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have have a page that is dynamically built by server-side logic.  The div at the top will always have a class named like 'namespace1' or 'namespace2' etc, actually the namespace count could go on to between namespace10 or 15 max.

So mostly, the event of clicking .myBtn should do one thing, but i need to have it do something completely different if the firt div has a class name of 'namespace5'

currently the code i have triggers all 3 event listners, what do i need to do to make only the 'hello 5' alert to trigger?

```
<div class="namespace5"><!-- namespace2 is dynamically set server-side-->
    <button class="myBtn">
        Test Button 5
    </button>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('.myBtn').on("click.namespace1.namespace2.namespace3.namespace4.namespace6", function(event){
        alert('hello not 5');
    });

    $('.myBtn').on("click.namespace5", function(event){
        alert('hello 5');
    });

    $('.myBtn').on("click", function(event){
        alert('!!');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the child of .namespace that has a class of .myBtn. Something like this should work:

```
$(' .namespace5 .myBtn ').on("click", function(event){
    alert('hello 5');
});
```

also, you can just check the .myBtn click and then use conditionals:

```
$('.myBtn').on("click", function(event){
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('.namespace1')) {
     //do whatever
    }
});
```

Edit: Had the parent and child elements backwards.

Comment: but in your example you are no longer using a javascript namespace.  only a classname that happens to have the name namespace.  I'm attempting to build very similar event listener rules that may change only very slightly on occasion.